# Convert.ToDecimal convert my value to 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have this line:

```
 miDetalle.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["#tbPrecioUnidad"]);
```

Precio is decimal on my model , when the programs checks the value of tbPrecioUnidad i has a value such as 6950, but when i check precio value it is 0.

what i'm doing wrong

Comment: What is Request.Form["#tbPrecioUnidad"].ToString() returning?

Comment: Have you run through Request.Form.AllKeys to make sure the key you're interested in exists and looks like you'd expect?  (ie: it likely has a prefix of some sort)

Comment: Why are you even using `Request.Form` instead of just passing the model back to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble("6950");
d.Dump(); // 6950
```

So I imagine the problem is `Request.Form["#tbPrecioUnidad"]` is `null` or `0`.

Put a break point in and verify it has a value.

Comment: i use decimal, 'cause is the data type i should enter to my database, with the break point the text box  tbPrecioUnidad value is 6950 with the case i'm testing, 'cause i'm using data base information, but when i look at miDetalle.precio value is 0, i'm using the same Convert.ToDecimal, with another text box value and variable and it works fine

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa If the textbox has the value use it, not `Request.Form`

Comment: My thoughts exactly. He should be passing the model back to the view, not doing a `Request.Form`

Comment: how i do that? for example i create the text box of this way  <% =Html.TextBox("tbPrecioUnidad")%>

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa Get Fiddler, trigger the POST event, and examine the POST Request that was sent through the inspector. Look at the Form tab. It will list all the data that was posted in the request in name/value sets. The Name column matches exactly the `Request.Form['Name']` If it's not there, there's your problem, fix your form. Also, post your Action method. It's not normal to use `Request.Form` to pull data in Asp.Net MVC, your Action should take a parameter that is your model type, and let the model binder do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: after 2 hours finally found my mistake, was so simple, but i don't know what i ignore it, "#tbPrecioUnidad the # is unnecesary here, thanks everyone, i look at all the form carefully again and find it!

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa I sort of assumed that was your control's name. Woops! :)

Comment: yes sorry, i'm sure that i look at the same line lots of times, but never realized that i have the # where i shouldn't ...

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa I always forget the hash in my jQuery and wonder for 2 hours why my select won't work!